# Best Java library for accessing Camera (JMF alternative)

Tags: camera, jmf

I would like to access a camera attached to my system. basically i would like to capture an image using the code retirieve the image. can someone suggest me a good framework. I went through JMF, but it was last updated 7 years ago. FMJ also lacks proper documentation. Is there any framework available which is good and has good userbase?

Answer (score 0):

Xuggler is pretty cool. It has tutorials too.